# Async callback in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to add for every statement I retrieve from a query a count for that statement. However callbacks happen async so count will only get executed when the for loop has already ended. What is good practice to do this kind of practices in mongoose?

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {

    Statement.find({}, function (err, statements) {
        if (err) throw err;

        for (var i = 1; i <= statements.length; i++) {

            var condition = JSON.parse("{ \"stmt"+i+"\" : 1 }");

            Record.count(condition, function (err, count) {
                if (err) throw err;

                statements[i].count = counts[i];
            });
        }

        res.render('index', {
            stmts: statements,
            title: 'Stemtest Visualization'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Use promises. Or the `async` library

Comment: can you give me an example on how to use promises here?

Comment: Similar question resolved in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/16120827/504377